# Exception in MVC - 3 view cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC-3. I am facing the following exception on my view :

```
cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

**Model class**

```
    public class HomeModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Html> Template { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Code**

```
@model Project.Models.HomeModel 

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        int i = 0;
    }
    <div class="container">
            @foreach (var e in Model.Template)    //getting exception on this foreach loop
            {
                 //loop content    
            }
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HomeModel model = new HomeModel();

    model.Template = db.Templates();

    return View(model);
}
```

My view is strongly typed to HomeModel model class. Can anyone please help me to solve this out?

Comment: What is db.Templates?  Other than null, that is.

Comment: Can you debug and inspect the value of db.Templates() on your Index action?

Comment: yes and this value is not null

Comment: db.Templates is a populated IEnumerable, then?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error. I would try doing the foreach loop in the index method itself and see if you get the error there too.  It might be a problem with db.Templates.

Comment: What is inside the foreach loop?

Comment: What might be happening here is that if db.Templates is LINQ then it might be deferring execution of the LINQ statement until the IEnumerable is interated over. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: Is your code in **View Code** in a file called `Index.cshtml`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips yes it is in Index.cshtml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the deferred execution of LINQ. The results of Model.Template are not calculated until you try to access them and in this case db.Template is out of scope from view. 
You can do it by using `ToList()` to `ToArray()` and `ToDictionary()` with `db.Templates`.

Your Controller's code should look like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HomeModel model = new HomeModel();

    model.Template = db.Templates.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```